# The "RegisterFormRegions" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: visual-studio-2015, outlook-addin

I am trying to create a simple Outlook 2013 Add-In in Visual Studio 2015,but the build fails with the following errors:

```
  The "RegisterFormRegions" task failed unexpectedly.
  System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
  assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime, Version=10.0.0.0, 
  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
```

Comment: Finally, i solve the problem by myself. It is the "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistribute"!!! I did not install it. 
After i reinstall the office 2013 by defult setting, all run ok.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue with Visual Studio 2013 and Outlook 2010 and found an **MSDN** Article **(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164304.aspx)** that states:

Starting in `Visual Studio 2013` Update 3, this task has a new signature that allows you to specify the target framework version for the file.

Although this doesn't apply to VS2012 it does appears that the versions of Office and targets is very much tied to the version of Visual Studio you are building it with. In my case I had to ensure I was building against VS2013 Update 3 when building against Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets `Version=12.0.0.0` so you may want to try that combination if all else is failing.

Comment: But my vs version is 2015. so, how should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime were missed.